# Getting permission error while running ADB command to make call

Tags: adb

While runing ADB command to make call. I am getting permission error Any help pls?

```
adb -s <serialno> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:555-5555

Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from null (pid=18175, uid=2000) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1718)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1671)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:3205)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:643)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:394)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:124)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:359)
```

Comment: please add detail process of what you are trying to do. error seems to be android issue if it is android add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ADB from a cmd window on Windows 10, the serial field should be encapsulated between " ". Replace the words SERIAL and MSISDN accordingly:

adb -s "SERIAL" shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d MSISDN

Also try with other commands to see if the phone responds, for example:

adb -s "SERIAL" shell getprop ro.product.model